# sendGrid set headers/content type

Tags: sendgrid

I'm looking to use sendGrid to create an outlook meeting request.

I need to be able to set the content type (header) to something specific, however does anyone know how I can do this? I presume I am to use the x-smtpapi, whilst accepting a json string.

Here is what I currently have.

```
$json_string = array(
'Content-Type' => array(
    'text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n',
    'text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n'
));
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try asking at https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, using SendGrid Web API there is no way to change the content type yet.

> In Web API, there's no way to force the content-type. In SMTP however, we'll respect whatever you set it to.

Reference: [this SendGrid support engineer answer](https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/change_top_level_content_type_when_using_web_api)

**Edit:**

The answer is 2 years old. You may have better luck asking again on https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid

Comment: Confirming this. As of now our WebAPI does not allow you to change this header. It is planned for our upcoming version however.