# how to add link in sendgrid message using html

Tags: php, sendgrid, codeigniter-3

I want to send a link using email in sendgrid

```
$html =  'click on this   <a href="' . current_url . site_url("/users/verfication?code=" . $code)  . '">link</a>  to verify your account';
```

but it just send plain text instead of rendering link like below message

```
click on this   <a href="//users/verfication code=283add227e43e2674980ce9bbcd34833">link</a> 
  to verify your account


$CI->email->to($to);
        $CI->email->subject($sub);
        $CI->email->message($html);
        $CI->email->send();
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the Sendgrid documentation? You need to format the mail to be HTML format, and there are a number of ways to do this (Swiftmail, Sendgrid API, etc.). See: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html and other docs...

Comment: @ldg it's php api. I am using codeigniter here
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/codeigniter.html

Comment: take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723653/sendgrid-set-headers-content-type

Comment: @DOZ I am not asking about changing header. i want to know how to render content.

Comment: I know, but I think you issue comes from here

Comment: @bawag Can you please take a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66760554/9409877

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass config in email library and need to assign email type as html

```
$config = Array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    ...etc...
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Comment: later i figured it out. however thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function `preg_replace`. Use a regular expression to detect a link and replace by the same link but with a `<a>`.

More info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
And this should also help : [Replace URLs in text with HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

Comment: sendgrid mail api is not rendring that.